# Get Height of Android Action Bar for portrait mode while in landscape mode in background process?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, height, android-orientation

I need to get the height of the Android Action Bar for portrait mode while running in a non-visual background process, no matter the orientation of the device.  I'm able to get the action bar height for the current orientation with this code:

```
        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();

        if (ctx.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
        {       
            actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
```

However I need to get the action bar height for portrait mode, no matter the orientation of the device.  Note:  This code is running in an IntentService not an Activity.
Thanks.